# Enumerating the list of figures / listoftables in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, roman-numerals

I'm fairly new in LaTeX and using TeXmaker to write my thesis.
My supervisor wants my toc to look like this:

```
TOC
I    TOC..................I
II   LOF.................II
III  LOT................III
IV   List of symbols.....IV
1    Prelude..............1
2    Theoretical part.....3
3    Main part............9
4    Summary.............20
5    Bibliography........22
6    Appendix............25
```

(page numbers chosen exemplary)

So basically it should have roman numbering for pages and sections including all my lists (except from bib), and arabic numbering for pages and sections including the relevant content of the paper.

I managed to produce this to the point where only the TOF and TOT don't have any section numbering, nor in the TOC, neither on the following pages. The page numbering is fine though.

My question now is: How can I enumerate the LOF, LOT with roman section numbers?

Thanks in advance for any help!

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, bibtotoc, bibtotocnumbered, liststotoc, toctotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0,4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand{\sectionnumbering}[1]{% 
  \setcounter{section}{0}% 
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\csname #1\endcsname{section}}
}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \section{title}
    asdf

    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \sectionnumbering{Roman}

    \newpage
    \section{presec1}
    asdf

    \newpage
    \section{presec2}
    asdf

    \newpage
    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \listoftables

    \newpage
    \section{list of symbols}
    asdf

    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \sectionnumbering{arabic}

    \newpage
    \section{prelude}
    asdf

    \newpage
    \section{theory}
    asdf

    \newpage
    \section{mainpart}
    asdf

    \newpage
    \section{summary}
    asdf

    \newpage
    \section{summary}
    asdf

    \newpage
    \section{appendix}
    asdf

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get numbered entries for a LOT, LOF and TOC in TOC with a KOMA-Script class use:

```
\KOMAoptions{listof=numbered}
\setupttoc{toc}{numbered}
```

BTW use `\cleardoubleoddpage` before `\pagenumbering`. I would replace `fancyhdr` by `scrlayer-scrpage` that is part of the KOMA-Script bundle.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{listof=numbered}% <- lists numberded and in TOC
\setuptoc{toc}{numbered}% <- toc numbered and in TOC

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}% maybe better: supcaption
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[automark,markcase=upper,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\newcommand{\sectionnumbering}[1]{%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\csname #1\endcsname{section}}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}%dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\sectionnumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\section{list of symbols}
asdf

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\sectionnumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]